# How to push a blessed model to S3 with TFX Pusher?

Tags: tfx

I would like to push a blessed model to an S3 bucket. The closest thing I could find is this which pushes a model to the google could ai platform. Is there a Pusher for S3 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The TFX model path tests check paths to S3 buckets, so I assume they are intechangeable with GCS bucket paths
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/b8bbe748c3ee84045d1d5d1d9ce3cdd4ebd52c17/tfx/utils/model_paths/tf_serving_flavor_test.py
What have you tried?